# how to get the total results count in pagination

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpa-criteria

I'm trying to get the count of total results from table in spring Data JPA but some how I am getting this error 
 **Query argument pattern not found in the list of parameters provided during query execution**.

below is what I tried:

```
CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = criteriaBuilder
  .createQuery(Long.class);
countQuery.select(criteriaBuilder
  .count(countQuery.from(Foo.class))).where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));

Long count = entityManager.createQuery(countQuery)
  .getSingleResult();
```

I found examples on google but with out predicates. when I include predicate I got the above exception.

Comment: Have a look at [this example](https://gist.github.com/ufuk/2ca63e392cc61d5b5277249dc23d4eca), line 63 where the count method is using predicate but their where clause is different. `.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicates[predicates.size()]));`

Comment: Same exception :(

Comment: Please help to add the exception